# how to say this in english

Tags: meaning, grammar

In Office around my desk there is no light.so due to darkness I feel problem in my eyes while working on computer. I want to write mail to Hr. how can I write formally.Any help.
thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about learning English.

Comment: why you think so.. how to write formal mail in English on particular situation.how can it be off topic?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request to have a letter or email written for the asker, not knowledge of the language.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To whom it may concern,

My office desk is not giving sufficient light. This is causing problems with my eyes when working on my computer.

Can this problem be rectified?

Thank you.

Neelam Prajapati

Comment: 5/10 for grammar.

Comment: Always give a reason or no-one learns